# Compare the limits of $(Z^2-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ above and below its branch cut.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, multivalued-functions

This question is taken from Q7 of example sheet 1 of the Complex Methods course at the university of Cambridge. The link for the sheet can be found below:

http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/examples/B7a.pdf

We define a branch of $f(z)=(z^2-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ as follows: Let $[-1,1]$ be the straight line segment connecting $-1$ and $1$ in $\mathbb{C}$. We consider the following branch of
$f(z)$:
$$
f_{2}:\mathbb{C}-[-1,1] \to \mathbb{C}
$$
where $f_{2}(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}-1}$ for $x>1$.

I'm trying to compare the limits of $f_{2}$ above and below the branch cut $[-1,1]$. In order to do so, I notice that $z^{2}-1=(z-1)(z+1)$.

Write
$$
z-1=r_{+}e^{i\theta_{+}}
$$
and $$
z+1=r_{-}e^{i\theta_{-}}
$$
where $\theta_{+} \in (-\pi,\pi)$ and $\theta_{-}\in(0,2\pi)$ based on the branch cut.

My understanding is that just above the brach cut $\theta_{-}=0$ and $\theta_{+}=\pi$ so $(z^2-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{r_{+}r_{-}}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}=i\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$.

Below the branch cut $\theta_{-}=2 \pi$ and $\theta_{+}=-\pi$ so $(z^2-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{r_{+}r_{-}}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}=i\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$.

The answer is wrong though. I'm not sure why and would appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote the principal branch of the square root with $S$, i.e.
$$
 S(re^{i \phi}) = \sqrt r e^{i \phi/2}
$$
for $r > 0$ and $-\pi < \phi< \pi$. Then $g(z) = S(z-1)S(z+1)$ is a holomorphic square root of $z^2-1$ on $D = \Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 1]$ and $g(x) = f_2(x)$ for $x > 1$.

It follows that $f_2(z) = S(z-1)S(z+1)$ for $z \in D$. For $z \to x \in (-1,1)$ converges $z-1 \to x-1 < 0$, so that
$$
 S(z-1) \to \begin{cases}
  i \sqrt{1-x} & \text{ from above,} \\
  -i \sqrt{1-x} & \text{ from below,} 
\end{cases}
$$
and $z+1 \to x+1 > 0$ so that $S(z+1) \to \sqrt{x+1}$. Then
$$
 f_2(z) \to \begin{cases}
  i \sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{x+1} = i\sqrt{1-x^2} & \text{ from above,} \\
  -i \sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{x+1} = -i\sqrt{1-x^2}& \text{ from below.} 
\end{cases}
$$

The error in your calculation is that both $\theta_+ = \arg(z-1)$ and $\theta_- = \arg(z+1)$ should be in the range $(-\pi, \pi)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see why your solution works. I’m not sure why it’s wrong for me to use the [-1,1] branch cut and the arguments of z-1 and a+1 I’ve used to determine the required limits.